# How to change default blog tempate in wordpress genesis framework?

Tags: wordpress, genesis

So I have a child theme which extends genesis framework.My child theme is basically using the Genesis blog article theme. I looked into the page_blog.php of the Genesis theme but it has only genesis loop running and says that code being used is in the file lib/structure/loop.php. I want to change the default blog article page, I want to show the author name, blog category, a published date which requires the change in the HTML. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

if I got it right, you need to override files in the parent theme by recreating them (at least copy them) into the child theme directory>> so you need to copy the  blog article page and change it,also you may need to create functions.php in the child for new functionalities
for more details https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options :

1. You can [create your own page_blog.php file](https://my.studiopress.com/documentation/snippets/miscellaneous/show-content-above-posts-on-blog-page/) in your child themes root directory and add code directly to the file and modify the default functionality.
2. Or you can select the blog page template and [use custom fields to control the query variables](https://wpsites.net/web-design/customize-genesis-blog-page-template-query-arguments/)